# selecting words separated with comma with PHP

Tags: php

A string contains some words separated by comma or space. Using PHP, I want to select first three words which have have minimum 4 characters(a-Z, 0-9, -, _, #).
For example

```
$words = aa, one, ab%c, four, five six#
```

How to select 'four', 'five', six# ? (probably with for each?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dalen's suggestion would run much faster if you have no strict requirements for characters allowed. But here is a regex solution since you mention character requirements.

```
$words = 'aa, one, ab%c, four, five six#';
preg_match_all('/([a-z0-9_#-]{4,})/i', $words, $matches);
print_r($matches);
```

And you'll just have to cut out what you want from the array after like in Dalen's answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
    //turn string to an array separating words with comma    
    $words = explode(',',$words);
    $selected = array();
    foreach($words AS $word)
    {
       //if the word has at least 4 chars put it into selected array
       if(strlen($word) > 3)
          array_push($selected,$word);
    }

    //get the first 3 words of the selected ones
    $selected = array_slice($selected, 0, 3);
```

this won't check for the characters, just for the length of the word.
you'll need to edit the condition with a regexp